# Why is this powershell code only returning one result when I have multiple results?

Tags: sql, database, powershell

I am running a query through powershell.  I know I have multiple results from running the query through ssms.  Why does the variable only have one result in powershell?

I have used many methods to do this query and I finally got it working but can't get all the results of the query.

```
[string] $Server= "mochqdb01";
[string] $Database = "MoCApp.Models.Item+ItemDBContext";
[string] $SQLQuery= $("Select smEmail from Items where DateRequested >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)");

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Database=$Database;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$dbname = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
$SqlConnection.Close()
Write-output "Database is " $dbname
```

Output:
Database is 
Franziew@marketyyo.com

Should have multiple results.  Should I save into an array?

I actually want to save the results into this format.

Send-ToEmail  -email  "js@marketyyo.com","mb@marketyyo.com";Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteScalar() returns the first column of the first row of the first result set.  You need [ExecuteReader()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader).  EG

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Database=$Database;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$rdr = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($rdr.Read())
{
   $smMail = $rdr[0]
   write-output "email is $smMail"
}
$rdr.Close()
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Heck yeah, thanks.  I was wondering if there is any way to get the emails into this format with the loop?  "js@marketyyo.com","mb@marketyyo.com"

Comment: You can just concatenate them to a variable declared outside of the loop.  eg `$to = $to + $rdr.GetString(0)`

Comment: Or you could do it in SQL Server `Select string_agg(concat('"',smEmail,'"'),', ')  smEmails from Items . . .`

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to call my function in the while loop that sends an email and pass the $smMail as a parameter.